# Silence shutting down

Tags: android, android-emulator, shutdown

I silence the phone on shutdown and then restore to sound when booted in order to avoid that terrible sound of the phone company.
To do that I use receivers for ShutDown and BootCompleted events.
The problem is that the company music sounds before than the shutdown event is triggeted, so I hear it.
Then I restart and no sound is heard because it is in silence mode, perfect!
So, any help with this? Any other event to listen?

Comment: Try setting `android:priority` of your broadcast receiver to a large number (ex. 1000 which is SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY)

Comment: Still doesn't work. This is what I did: `
<receiver android:name=".clsReceiver">  
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000">  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />    
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF" />              
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>  `

Comment: Ok, it seems it's not possible to receive poweroff broadcast before carrier sounds. In other words poweroff event broadcasts after the sound plays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The famous(?) Silent boot app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antweb.silentboot) is unable to do this as well so a guess is that it not doable/trivial at least.

Not without rom/root hacking like (re)moving the sound file or adding something to power off menu for example. Some phones have this as the shutdown sound: /system/media/audio/ui/shutdown.ogg

Comment: Yes. I found it, but I cannot delete it. Any idea?

Comment: Requires root as I mentioned :-/